# Shared preferences? (Extremely simple issue!?)

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, string

**I am just trying to store the users input from an editText in a Shared Preference, but it is not working:**

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {

        Log.v(TAG, keyword.getString("keyword", "mDefault")); //IT LOGS OUT THE DEFAULT STRING EVEN **AFTER** STORING THE PREFERENCES BEFORE

        if (keycode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().toString());

            keywordEditor.putString("keyword", editText.getText().toString());
            keywordEditor.commit();

            Log.v(TAG, keyword.getString("keyword", "default")); //CORRECT! THIS LINE WORKS
            }
        }
    return true;
});
```

When I first edit the text, I will first get a log of "`mDefault`" which is normal, since nothing is stored in the shared preference.

Then, I store something in the shared preference, and to make sure it stored, I log and I get a log of what I typed. **Which means the shared preference data WAS stored.**

**Heres the problem:** After I have stored something in the shared preference, I go to a different activity, and I come back, and all the data stored in the shared preference is **GONE!**

**The very first log still says `mDefault` after navigating through activities.**

What could the problem be?

**EDIT:**

Here is my instantiation:

`onCreate`:

```
 keyword = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //Making a shared preferences
        keywordEditor = keyword.edit();
```

Comment: How do you get the `keyword` instance?

Comment: @Codebender In `onCreate`: `keyword = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //Making a shared preferences
        keywordEditor = keyword.edit();`

Comment: @Codebender I edited my question

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I have seen your message in my other answer, well you must set a preference name, to set and retrieve the values in any point of your app., see my answer.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I just recreated your example and seems to be working for me.  Without seeing more code it would be very difficult to solve this problem.

Comment: @Naveed Did it work even after leaving the activity and coming back to it?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Yes, it did for launching new activity and then coming back.  Even if I close the app swipe away and come back. It still works since the values are persisted

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I have added my example which currently working for me. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't save on setOnEditorActionListener. Save when you go to a different activity. Because when it goes to different activity the setOnEditorActionListener editText.getText().toString() it returns null.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you are saying. Do you mind providing more information? Isn't doing `.commit()` supposed to save it? Please let me know! :)

Comment: Please use  getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); if you use the getDefaultSharedPreferences there might be the key "keyword" and it cleared when back to the activity

Comment: I will need to access this shared preference from another activity though also. What do you mean there might be the key "keyword" that cleared when back to the activity? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. You can also access from another activity to this sharedpreference with the  name getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

**Very important:** you need a **Preference name** (for example: "MY_PREFS_NAME") to set and retrieve the values:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor keywordEditor = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Use the same constant Preference name and it will give you the same preferences in any point of your app.

Comment: and what is difference between **getDefaultSharedPreferences** and **getSharedPreferences** in store and retrieve value ?

Comment: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` is completely valid to use and will give the same name every single time. If you look at the source code it uses the package name appended with "_preferences" for the file name so that is not the issue here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Elenasys! Yes, I am having the same confusion as Naveed...whats wrong with `.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`, and why does it reset after leaving and coming back to the activity?

Comment: So why use this method instead? And what is the difference between the two? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Also, can I retrieve from a different activity with this?

Comment: @Naveen: Is it possible to reference this file on the phone internal storage? I could not find it.

Comment: @RuchirBaronia `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)` simply [calls `context.getSharedPreferences("$packageName_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` internally](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:preference/preference/src/main/java/androidx/preference/PreferenceManager.java;l=109-128). `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` is where AndroidX Preferences stores its preferences from your [user-defined settings XML (which is surfaced as a user interface)](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/settings)

Comment: @XMAN The file appears to be saved to `$dataDir/shared_prefs/$fileName.xml` based on the [internal implementation](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/refs/heads/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=929-932;drc=7346c436e5a11ce08f6a80dcfeb8ef941ca30176;bpv=0;bpt=1)

Answer (score 0):

STORING PREFERENCES:

```
   SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // We need an editor object to make changes
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();

   // Set/Store data
   edit.putString("username", "Rishabh");
   edit.putString("password", "rishabh123");

   // Commit the changes
   edit.commit();
```

RETRIEVING PREFERENCES:

```
  SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   String username = pref.getString("username", "");
   String password= pref.getString("password", "");

   Log.d(TAG, username);
   Log.d(TAG, password);
```

Comment: how do I access it from a different activity then?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an example in case you missed a key components.  This is currently working for me:

```
public class Main2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private SharedPreferences keyword;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor keywordEditor;
    private String TAG = "TAG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        keyword = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); //Making a shared preferences
        keywordEditor = keyword.edit();

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text);


        findViewById(R.id.btn_launch).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main22Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Initial: " + keyword.getString("keyword", "mDefault")); //IT LOGS OUT THE DEFAULT STRING EVEN **AFTER** STORING THE PREFERENCES BEFORE

                if (keycode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString());

                    keywordEditor.putString("keyword", editText.getText().toString());
                    keywordEditor.commit();

                    Log.v(TAG, "Saving in prefs: " + keyword.getString("keyword", "default")); //CORRECT! THIS LINE WORKS
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

From a fresh install:

I typed in "test" and hit the send button on keyboard therefore invoked the `onEditorAction`

Then clicked on launch new activity -> hit back button and typed in "test2" and hit send button.

The following is the log out put:

```
02-29 23:26:42.068 18105-18105/com.example.naveed.myapplication V/TAG: Initial: mDefault
02-29 23:26:42.136 18105-18105/com.example.naveed.myapplication V/TAG: Saving in prefs: test

02-29 23:26:53.281 18105-18105/com.example.naveed.myapplication V/TAG: Initial: test
02-29 23:26:53.338 18105-18105/com.example.naveed.myapplication V/TAG: Saving in prefs: test2
```

As you can see initially it was "mDefault" then "test" was saved.  I launched a new activity and came back.  Next time the initial was "test" since it was saved last time and "test2" was the new value saved.

Comment: Thats odd, because that is how mine looks, but mine isn't working. I am using multiple different Shared Preferences (4), could that be the problem? Could it be storage space?

Comment: Yeah it can fail if you have insufficient storage on the device.  But as long as you are saving and retrieving the preferences with same name  in your case getDefaultPreferences() it should work.

Comment: Can I have multiple shared preference objects?

Comment: As long as they point to different files, yes.  Calling getSharedPreferences() will return the object pointing to the same file unless you specify the different name.

Comment: @Naveed: Upvoted your comment and this solution- thanks. I'm a bit confused about when to use `SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());` and `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("preffilename", 0);`? I do understand that the latter lets you specify more than one pref file; however, I see most people using this approach over `PreferenceManager`- even if they are only using a single file to save prefs. Can you clarify?

Comment: Its just a matter of preference when it comes to single file use.  `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` will generate a file name for you while `getSharedPreferences()` will let you specify one.  Shared preferences are saved in your applications internal storage so they won't be visible to any other application and you won't be able to find the file unless your phone is rooted.  `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` can be called anywhere not just within an activity as long as you have a context available.

Answer (score 0):

Create `SharedPreferences` class

```
  public class SharedPreferenceClass
{
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;
    // Editor for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    // Context
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "INTELLIJ_AMIYO";

    public static final String KEY_SET_VALUE= "KEY_SET_VALUE";

    public SharedPreferenceClass(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void setUserDATA(String data)
    {
        editor.remove(KEY_SET_VALUE);
        editor.putString(KEY_SET_VALUE, data);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getUserDATA()
    {
        String  getData= pref.getString(KEY_SET_VALUE, null);
        return getData;
    }

 }
```

Now call this in your Activity section globally

```
SharedPreferenceClass        sharedPrefClassObj;
```

& call **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** section

```
   sharedPrefClassObj = new SharedPreferenceClass(getApplicationContext());
```

Now add this

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {


        if (keycode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            editText.setText(editText.getText().toString());
            sharedPrefClassObj.setUserDATA(editText.getText().toString()); // Set data 
            // Get data sharedPrefClassObj.getUserDATA();

            }
        }
    return true;
});
```